# how to spawn a SKnode on a loop that is in a different class - swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nodes, subclass

I am creating a shooting game and i am trying to create a firing method but my current method only spawns one bullet at a time when clicked. I have my bullet defined as a SKnode subclass and calling it in my touches began method in my gameScene.swift. Here's how

```
class Bullet1: SKNode {

var Bullet1:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()
var Bullet1Animaton:SKAction?

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init () {

    super.init()
}
func createBullet1s (){
    let wait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration( CFTimeInterval(0.25))
    let block:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock(createBullet1)
    let seq2:SKAction = SKAction.sequence( [block, wait])
    SKAction.repeatActionForever(seq2)
    self.runAction(seq2, withKey:"droneAction")

}
func createBullet1() {

    Bullet1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")
    Bullet1.xScale = 0.5
    Bullet1.yScale = 0.5
    Bullet1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Bullet1.size)
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet1
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy1 
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.addChild(Bullet1)
    self.name = "Bullet1"
}

}
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent  
event:UIEvent?) {

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent 
event:UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(joystick.frame, location)) {
            stickActive = true
            fireWeapon = true
        }else{
            stickActive = false
        }

if stickActive == true && fireWeapon == true{  if fireWeapon == false 
{}

let bulletAction = SKAction.runBlock({
let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - self.joystickBase.position.x, dy: 
location.y - self.joystickBase.position.y)
let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
print(deg + 180) // prints degree in debugging
self.hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with angle of joy 
stic

let bullet1:Bullet1 = Bullet1()
bullet1.createBullet1()

bullet1.position = CGPoint (x: self.hero.position.x , y: 
self.hero.position.y) // Bullet spawn @ anchor point
let xDist:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 //bullet spawn location
let yDist:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 //bullet spawn location

bullet1.position = CGPointMake( self.hero.position.x - xDist, 
self.hero.position.y + yDist) //spawning bullet @ defined location

let xDistMove:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 //Bullet max x 
distance
let yDistMove:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 //Bullet max y 
distance

let bulletMovementY = SKAction.moveToY(self.hero.position.y + 
yDistMove, duration: 1) //Bullet y speed
let bulletMovementX = SKAction.moveToX(self.hero.position.x - 
xDistMove, duration: 1) //Bullet x speed

bullet1.runAction(bulletMovementY)
bullet1.runAction(bulletMovementX)

self.addChild(bullet1)
})
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.25)
let completeSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletAction, wait])
let repeatShootingActionForever =
SKAction.repeatActionForever(completeSequence)
self.runAction(repeatShootingActionForever, withKey: "BulletAction")
        }

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: 
UIEvent?) {

for touch in touches {
let location = touch.locationInNode(self
if (stickActive == true) {

let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - joystickBase.position.x, dy: 
location.y - joystickBase.position.y)
let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
let length: CGFloat = joystickBase.frame.size.height / 2                   
print(deg + 180) // prints degree in debugging

joystick.position = location

hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with angle of joy stick

if (CGRectContainsPoint(joystickBase.frame, location)) {
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: 
UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

if stickActive == true && fireWeapon == true{  if fireWeapon == false 
{}

let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - joystickBase.position.x, dy: 
location.y - joystickBase.position.y)
let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)//converts radains to degrees and 
generates a degree when touchesmove == true
let length: CGFloat = joystickBase.frame.size.height / 2 //sets maximum 
distance for joystick ball
print(deg + 180) // prints degree in debugging

joystick.position = location

self.hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with   
angle of joy stick
let xDist:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 //bullet spawn location
let yDist:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 //bullet spawn location

bullet1.position = CGPointMake( self.hero.position.x - xDist, 
self.hero.position.y + yDist) //spawning bullet @ defined location

let xDistMove:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 //Bullet max x     
distance
let yDistMove:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 //Bullet max y 
distance

let bulletMovementY = SKAction.moveToY(self.hero.position.y +   
yDistMove, duration: 1) //Bullet y speed
let bulletMovemenX = SKAction.moveToX(self.hero.position.x - xDistMove, 
duration: 1) //Bullet x speed

            bullet1.runAction(bulletMovementY)
            bullet1.runAction(bulletMovemenX)
}}
```

as you can see i need to call my bullet method in my touches began since the bullet spawn location is coordinated with a joystick. The current method only spawn 1 bullet when clicked instead of creating a new bullet every 0.25 seconds when the joystick is held down like i attempted in my createBullet1s method. If anyone can help me out i would be very grateful! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the values have to be new calculated for every bullet then something like this would be the way to go i guess (add `self.` before every node Name):

```
if stickActive == true && fireWeapon == true{  if fireWeapon == false      
{}
let shootingAction = SKAction.runBlock({
    let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - joystickBase.position.x, dy: 
    location.y - joystickBase.position.y)
    let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
    let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)//converts radains to degrees and  
        generates a degree when touchesmove == true 
        print(deg + 180) 
        let bullet1:Bullet1 = Bullet1()
        self.bullet1.createBullet1s()

        self.bullet1.position = CGPoint (x: self.hero.position.x , y: self.hero.position.y) 
        let xDist:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 
        let yDist:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 
        self.bullet1.position = CGPointMake(self.hero.position.x - xDist,self.hero.position.y + yDist) 

        let xDistMove:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 
        let yDistMove:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 

        let bulletMovementY = SKAction.moveToY(self.hero.position.y + yDistMove, 
        duration: 1) 
        let bulletMovemenX = SKAction.moveToX(self.hero.position.x - xDistMove,   
        duration: 1) 
        let wait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(CFTimeInterval(0.25))

        self.addChild(self.bullet1)

        let groupMovement = SKAction.group([bulletMovementY,bulletMovementX])
        let removeNode = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let sequenceMovementWithWait = SKAction.sequence([wait,groupMovement,removeNode])
        self.hero.runAction(sequenceMovementWithWait)
        self.hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 
    })

let repeatShootingActionForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(shootingAction)
self.runAction(repeatShootingActionForever, withKey: "BulletAction"))
```

if the values can stay the same for each bullet maybe something like this would be enough:

```
        let bulletAction = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.addChild(self.bullet1)
        let groupAction = SKAction([bulletMovementY,bulletMovementX])
        let removeNode = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let finalSequenceWithWait = SKAction.sequence([wait,groupAction,removeNode])
        self.bullet1.runAction(finalSequenceWithWait)
        })
        let repeatBulletActionForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(bulletAction)
        self.runAction(repeatBulletActionForever, withKey: "BulletAction")
```

For both ways i would say in `TouchesEnded`:

```
self.removeActionForKey("BulletAction")
```

Edit:

Okay .. You have a SKNode subclass where you add the bullets (SpriteNodes) to the SKNode. By the way - it's complicated because you gave the SpriteNodes and the SKNode the same name. However, the bullets (SpriteNodes) gets added to the SKNode and the SKNode gets added in the GameScene. Now we "spawn" and "remove" this SKNode in the gamescene, but we only add SpriteNodes to the SKNode and we don't remove them there.

Do you want multiple bullets at the same time to be visible in the GameScene? If you need only 1 bullet at a time visible (but repeated) i would say maybe it would help to remove the Bullet (SpriteNode) from your SKNode like we did in the GameScene.

Imagine that:

```
- GameScene creates a SKNode. (your class Bullet1)
- SKNode creates Child SpriteNode
- GameScene removes the SKNode.
- GameScene creates another SKNode. (again your class Bullet1)
- SKNode wants to create Child SpriteNode
-> Error: SpriteNode already exists.
```

So we need to edit your class.

```
//class Bullet1
func createBullet1() {
if Bullet1.parent == nil{
    Bullet1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet.png")
    Bullet1.xScale = 0.5
    Bullet1.yScale = 0.5
    Bullet1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Bullet1.size)
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet1
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy1 
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Bullet1.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    self.addChild(Bullet1)
    self.name = "Bullet1"
    }
else{
    Bullet1.removeFromParent()
}
}
```

Oh, and we need to wait 0.25secs before adding a new SKNode so that the animation is done. In your GameScene edit this part:

```
let repeatShootingActionForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(shootingAction)
self.runAction(repeatShootingActionForever, withKey: "BulletAction"))
```

to this:

```
let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.25)
let runShootingAction = SKAction.runBlock(shootingAction)
let completeSequence = SKAction.sequence([wait,runShootingAction])
let repeatShootingActionForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(completeSequence)
self.runAction(repeatShootingActionForever, withKey: "BulletAction"))
```

I bet there are better solutions for that, im not an expert in Swift, too. You have to test that .. sorry.

Another edit:
You did not tell which zRotation the bullet should have.

Try this (where you have `bulletAction = SKAction.runBlock`):

```
let bulletAction = SKAction.runBlock({
let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - self.joystickBase.position.x, dy: location.y - self.joystickBase.position.y)
let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)//converts radains to degrees and generates a degree when touchesmove == true
print(deg + 180) // prints degree in debugging
let bullet1:Bullet1 = Bullet1()

bullet1.position = CGPoint (x: self.hero.position.x , y: self.hero.position.y) // Bullet spawn @ anchor point
bullet1.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with angle of joy stick
let xDist:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 //bullet spawn location
let yDist:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 35 //bullet spawn location

bullet1.position = CGPointMake( self.hero.position.x - xDist, self.hero.position.y + yDist) //spawning bullet @ defined location

bullet1.createBullet1()    

let xDistMove:CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 //Bullet max x distance
let yDistMove:CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.5709633) * 700 //Bullet max y distance

let bulletMovementY = SKAction.moveToY(self.hero.position.y+yDistMove, duration: 1) //Bullet y speed
let bulletMovemenX = SKAction.moveToX(self.hero.position.x -xDistMove, duration: 1) //Bullet x speed
let wait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration( CFTimeInterval(0.25))
// let bulletFire = SKAction.sequence([wait,bulletMovemenX, bulletMovementY])
self.addChild(bullet1)

bullet1.runAction(wait)
bullet1.runAction(bulletMovementY)
bullet1.runAction(bulletMovemenX)

self.hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with angle of joy stick
})
```

Last Edit:
I can't see in your updated method the bullet1.zRotation so i guess you want only the hero to Change the zRotation.

However, if the zRotation only changes in `touchesBegan`and not in `touchesMoved` i would say you should make `angle` a global variable which can be changed in both methods. Maybe this helps, because hero gets his zRotation depending on the value of `angle` (i think).

1. Make `angle` a global variable and add a variable which tells you if your touch is moved or not:

   ```
   class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
       var angle = CGFloat() // It should be a CGFloat, right?
       var touchesMovedOn = false
   ```
2. Edit this part from `touchesBegan`:

   ```
   let bulletAction = SKAction.runBlock({
   let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - self.joystickBase.position.x, dy: location.y - self.joystickBase.position.y)
   let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
   let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
   print(deg + 180) // prints degree in debugging
   self.hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with angle of joystic
   ```

to this:

```
    let bulletAction = SKAction.runBlock({
    let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - self.joystickBase.position.x, dy: location.y - self.joystickBase.position.y)
    if touchesMovedOn == false{
        angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
    }
    let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)
    print(deg + 180) // prints degree in debugging
    self.hero.zRotation = angle - 1.57079633 //rotates with angle of joystic
```

3. Edit this part from `touchesMoved`:

   ```
   let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - joystickBase.position.x, dy: location.y - joystickBase.position.y)
   let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
   let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)//converts radains to degrees and generates a degree when touchesmove == true
   let length: CGFloat = joystickBase.frame.size.height / 2 //sets Maximum distance for joystick ball
   print(deg + 180) // prints degree in Debugging to this:
   ```

to this:

```
    touchesMovedOn = true
    let v = CGVector(dx: location.x - joystickBase.position.x, dy: location.y - joystickBase.position.y)
    angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx) //where angle is defined "in radians"
    let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / M_PI)//converts radains to degrees and generates a degree when touchesmove == true
    let length: CGFloat = joystickBase.frame.size.height / 2 //sets Maximum distance for joystick ball
    print(deg + 180) // prints degree in Debugging to this:
```

4. Add this line in `touchesEnded`

   ```
   touchesMovedOn = false
   ```

If this not helps i really Need the Project as i would have to test it myself where the Problem is. So i hope it works now. Best luck ! And as i said, im sure there are better Solutions for this, so in the future you should look out to make the code better. ;-)

Comment: thank you for the help! I implemented your first method however i get a new error that says attempt to add SKsprite node that already has a parent @aignetti

Comment: and the app crashes. i would want to go with the first method since the spawn location of the bullet will almost never be the same since it is coordinated to the 1 millionth of the angle degree of the joystick @aignetti

Comment: I think its very complicated because in your gamescene you are adding your custom SKNode Class. And in this SKNode class you are adding the SpriteNodes. So both needs to get repeated. I have edit my post - test it, but i don't know if this will work.

Comment: ok, i edit your answer just a little to get this (UPDATED QUESTION) this method works except it only launches the bullet at angle - 1.5709633, it doesn't update the bullet spawn location to the updated degree of the joystick. Do i have too change something in my touches moved? Or...? i really appreciate your help by the way

Comment: Hi, okay .. hm i can't imagine what the Problem could be .. do you mean the zRotation of the bullet or the Position? Would it be possible to upload your Project (with Folders and Files in it)? So i could test where the Problem could be. Only with the code it's hard to find out.

Comment: yes, the z rotation, the bullet only spawns at the first degree of the angle angle that the joystick generates, the degree of the angle updates in the debugger to match the joystick but the bullet spawn location does update with the joystick, it just keeps looping on the first location.   added, my touches moved method to my question as well i think thats where i need to fix the problem. I'm sorry i do not know how to upload the whole project @aignetti

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything :( , you're help is getting me closer and closer though haha. I am super close, ok I'm going to update my question hopefully for the last time. With this method, the bullet spawn location does update, however it only updates when a new tap of the joystick is recognized. Because a new degree is created every time the joystick is tapped it spawns to that degree but when the joystick is moved around, the bullet spawn location is not updated. @aignetti